# Android Tabview Inside a Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I want to create an Activity which has a header on top and a TabHost beneath it. This is what I have in my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/formheader" />
    <TabHost android:id="@+id/distributionTabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget android:id="@+id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textview2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is another tab" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textview3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a third tab" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

if you observe I have a header included

```
    <include layout="@layout/formheader" />
```

My activity class inherits from Activity, not TabActivity. Here's the code for that

```
public class DistributionActivity extends android.app.Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.distribution);

        TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.distributionTabhost);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Tab 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION at the addTab line. Can someone guide me on how to create an activity which not only has a Tab, but other controls.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem

```
mTabHost.setup();
```

Had to add the following line after setContentView()

Comment: Hi Did you actually manage to put the tab layout within the linear layout ? I thought that the tabhost has to be the root node ?

Answer (score 2):

As of API Level 10 the above fails with:

> E/AndroidRuntime(19550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity ...
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your TabHost must have a TabWidget whose
>   id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabs'

Change the TabWidget id to the following:

```
<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"...
```

and all is good.